# strapi v4: How to create a Entry with Relation?

Tags: javascript, next.js, strapi

When I create a new entry in my Collection-Type all of the values for the fields get added to the newly created entry EXCEPT for the value for the field with the Relation type.

So for example in my event Collection-Type I have name, performers, venue, address, date, time, description and user

user is a Relation type (Relation with User (from:users-permission))

The rest are either Text, DateTime, RichText, etc.

after I get the data from the form I end up having a object similar to:

```
var values = {
        name: 'namevalue',
        performers: 'whatever',
        venue: 'whatever',
        address: 'xyz address',
        date: '2022-12-15',
        time: '10:00 PM',
        description: 'Description of the Event',
    }
```

I then just edit the values object above to get the final version of value as

```
var values = {
            name: 'namevalue',
            performers: 'whatever',
            venue: 'whatever',
            address: 'xyz address',
            date: '2022-12-15',
            time: '10:00 PM',
            description: 'Description of the Event',
            user:1
        }
```

PLEASE TAKE NOTE OF the `user:1` added to the object above

However after submitting the above values to the correct endpoint:

```
const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/api/events`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                data: values,
            }),
        })
```

In the Strapi backend the user field and value totally does not show up....
For example this is what I get:

```
{
  data: {
    name: '13',
    performers: '13',
    venue: '13',
    address: '13',
    date: '2022-06-10',
    time: '8:00 PM',
    description: '13'
  },
  files: undefined
}
```

As you can see the rest of the data I get and it then gets added to the newly created Entry but WITHOUT the Relation value that I need and want.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this????

Answer (score 2):

Go to your settings -> user-permission settings -> authenticated -> user permission

under the user section enable find and findOne scopes and should work

Comment: You saved my day. May the sun shine whereever you go

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding to the url `?populate=*`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34316479)